# Calculating the average difference in days within a period

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the average difference between two columns in excel. The columns contain a  planned and an actual date, I would like to get the average difference but only for planned dates within the last three months.

Example:

Planned Start Date | Actual Start Date

21/09/2013         | 25/09/2013 
10/07/2014         | 16/07/2014 
01/06/2014         | 30/06/2014

The formula should only take line 2 & 3 (line 1 is older than 3 months), look at the difference in days for each applicable line (line 2: 6 days, line 3: 29 days) and then show the average ( 17.5 days) of all applicable lines.

Does anybody have a formula for this? Excel really isn't my strong suit...

Comment: Give the example of data and what values do you expect to get. This will make it much easier for us to give you the solution.

Comment: Just added an example, hope that makes it a bit more clear @taosique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your data is in A2:B4 then try this `array` formula

```
=AVERAGE(IF(TODAY()-A2:A4<=90,B2:B4-A2:A4))
```

- It assumes each month is 30 days (hence the `90`)
- Press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` to enter the formula as an array formula

Based on your example I get a result of 17.5 days.

Comment: That does the trick, thanks! I assume it is just a minor change, but what if I want to do the same for items between 90 and 180 days?

Comment: `=AVERAGE(IF(AND(TODAY()-A2:A4 > 90, TODAY()-A2:A4 <=180)), B2:B4-A2:A4))` NB - I just wrote this without testing so check the parentheses are all present and correct